# Scalable, high workload data structures and for web app

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, scalability, amazon-rds

We're currently working on a web app that utilizes a matchmaking like system. That is, a system in which a user can enter a queue to find a team, similar to that of popular online multiplayer games today. We are using amazon web services' EC2 and RDS options for server and database functionality. We envision the matchmaking data structure to be very dynamic in size (users added and removed frequently), with fast search or sort capabilities.

We've ran in to a bit of a roadblock, as we have little experience in web design. We considered maintaining a table of users currently looking for group in our mysql database, but we think that this may deviate from the canonical purpose of a RDS database. Alternatively, we've considered using some sort of server RAM for maintaining this data structure or queue, but we are not quite sure how to proceed.

How, in general, are these sort of very active data structures implemented in web applications, and what are typical solutions for handling the sort of user hop-in hop-out functionality a matchmaking system requires?

We would be very grateful if someone could point us in the direction of some useful literature, tools, or methods for correctly implementing a highly dynamic, scalable, sort-able or searchable, data structure with devoted processing power for a web app.